# How to make custom tab with arrow on selected tab?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-tabs

I want to implement tab like design but with an arrow pointing downward when the tab or the view is selected. 
This is the sample image of what I want to achieve.

[image: tab view with arrow pointing downward when selected]

Please anybody help me.